# How do you create a report of reports?

Tags: powershell-extensions

In SPE I need to create a report where each record has a link. When the link is clicked additional parameters are provided to the second report.

How would I go about creating such a report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed while reviewing the [official SPE docs](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/reports/authoring-reports) that it's possible to add custom links into the report.

Start by creating a script module containing your primary and secondary reports.

[image: First Example]

**Contents of Second Report**

```
Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $parameter1 | Select-Object -Property * | Show-ListView -Property Name, ID, ItemPath
```

**Contents of First Report**

```
Import-Function Render-ReportField
Close-Window

$script = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{6BC2FA09-3733-4B3F-9D6C-6F7FA8EE20D7}"

$props = @{
    Property = @(
        "Name",
        "ID"
        @{Label="More"; Expression={ Render-ScriptInvoker $script @{parameter1=$_.ID;} "Run Second Report" }.GetNewClosure() }
    )
    InfoTitle = "Report Reporter"
    InfoDescription = "More details"
}

Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\content\home" -WithParent | Show-ListView @props
```

**Notes:**

- The first report uses `Render-ScriptInvoker` to execute another script.
- The expression takes the script item, parameters made available in the script, and the display text.
- The use of `GetNewClosure()` is so that we can leverage `$_` in the hashtable used for splatting with `Show-ListView`.
- Not sure why, but using `Show-ListView` in the second report script required me to use explicit property names rather than relying on the default values or using `*`. SPE must be reusing a list of property names.